# ReactJS - Creating form field components dynamically and then saving the data from those fields to an object on form submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am brand new to React and things are coming along nicely, but I am getting stuck really badly on this concept. I've been at this point for a couple of days now and I think my brain is just getting overwhelmed by all the new concepts.

I work in a job where I help customers implement some controls that the company sells in their projects. I work with our .NET desktop stuff mostly. My team is doing a side project to create what is basically a StrawPoll clone for the sake of learning React/Node/MongoDB and getting more experience with a full development life cycle since most of what we do is just little code snippets.

I've got some of the basic components set up, but I'm getting really confused when it comes to creating and working with dynamically created components. If someone could show me what to do or explain what to do I would appreciate it so much.

You can find the branch I'm working on here: https://github.com/TylerBarlock/gcCE-Survey/tree/poll-components-cont

The part I'm currently stuck on is in src/Components/Poll/PollCreate.js and PollCreateAnswerOption.js

PollCreate.js:

```js
//Main component for poll creation

import React, { Fragment, useState, useRef } from "react";
import PollCreateAnswerOption from "./PollCreateAnswerOption";

const PollCreate = (props) => {
  // const [enteredTitle, setEnteredTitle] = useState("");
  // const [enteredDescription, setEnteredDescription] = useState("");
  const [enteredAnswer, setEnteredAnswer] = useState("");

  const [selectedPrivate, setSelectedPrivate] = useState("");
  const [selectedMultiple, setSelectedMultiple] = useState("");
  const [selectedLogin, setSelectedLogin] = useState("");
  const [selectedIpcheck, setSelectedIpcheck] = useState("");

  const enteredTitleRef = useRef();
  const enteredDescriptionRef = useRef();
  const enteredAnswerRef = useRef();

  const titleChangeHandler = (event) => {
    //setEnteredTitle(event.target.value);
  };

  const descriptionChangeHandler = (event) => {
    //setEnteredDescription(event.target.value);
  };

  const answerOptionChangeHandler = (answer) => {
    //setEnteredAnswer(answer);
  };

  const privateSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    setSelectedPrivate(event.target.value);
  };

  const multipleSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    setSelectedMultiple(event.target.value);
  };

  const loginSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    setSelectedLogin(event.target.value);
  };

  const ipcheckSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    setSelectedIpcheck(event.target.value);
  };

  const addAnswerOptionHandler = (event) => {
    console.log("add answer clicked");
  };

  const deleteAnswerOptionHandler = (event) => {
    console.log("delete clicked");
  };

  const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    //cancel default form submit behavior (reloads page)
    event.preventDefault();

    const enteredTitle = enteredTitleRef.current.value;
    const enteredDescription = enteredDescriptionRef.current.value;
    //const enteredAnswer = enteredAnswerRef.current.value;

    //object to hold all data about the new poll being created
    const newPollData = {
      title: enteredTitle,
      description: enteredDescription,
      answerOptions: [
        {
          id: enteredAnswer.id,
          text: enteredAnswer.text,
        },
      ],
      options: {
        private: selectedPrivate,
        multiple: selectedMultiple,
        login: selectedLogin,
        ipcheck: selectedIpcheck,
      },
    };
    //send the new poll data up to the Poll component
    props.onSaveNewPoll(newPollData);

    console.log(newPollData.title);
    console.log(newPollData.description);
    console.log(newPollData.answerOptions);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
        <h2 className="mb-4 text-center">Create a Poll</h2>
        <div className="text-left">
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 mb-4">
            <h4 className="mb-2">Title</h4>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Ask your question..."
              onChange={titleChangeHandler}
              ref={enteredTitleRef}
            ></input>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="text-left">
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 mb-4">
            <h4 className="mb-2">Description (optional)</h4>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Describe the poll..."
              onChange={descriptionChangeHandler}
              ref={enteredDescriptionRef}
            ></input>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="text-left">
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 mb-2 formtext">
            <h4 className="mb-2">Answer Options</h4>
            <PollCreateAnswerOption
              onAnswerOptionChange={answerOptionChangeHandler}
              ref={enteredAnswerRef}
              onAnswerOptionDelete={deleteAnswerOptionHandler}
            />
            <div className="flex">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="mb-3 formtext w-full"
                placeholder="Add an answer..."
                onChange={answerOptionChangeHandler}
              ></input>
              <button
                className="btn-alt-onwhite p-1 h-9"
                type="button"
                onClick={deleteAnswerOptionHandler}
              >
                X
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="flex">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="mb-3 formtext w-full"
                placeholder="Add an answer..."
                onChange={answerOptionChangeHandler}
              ></input>
              <button
                className="btn-alt-onwhite p-1 h-9"
                type="button"
                onClick={deleteAnswerOptionHandler}
              >
                X
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          className="btn-primary mb-2"
          type="button"
          onClick={addAnswerOptionHandler}
        >
          Add Answer
        </button>
        <div className="text-left">
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 mb-6">
            <h4 className="mb-2">Options</h4>
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                value=""
                className="mx-3"
                onChange={privateSelectedHandler}
              ></input>
              <p>Private (only via direct link)</p>
            </div>
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                value=""
                className="mx-3"
                onChange={multipleSelectedHandler}
              ></input>
              <p>Allow multiple choices</p>
            </div>
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                value=""
                className="mx-3"
                onChange={loginSelectedHandler}
              ></input>
              <p>Voters must log in to vote</p>
            </div>
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                value=""
                className="mx-3"
                onChange={ipcheckSelectedHandler}
              ></input>
              <p>Check for duplicate IP</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn-primary mx-2">
          Create Poll
        </button>
        <button type="button" className="btn-alt-onwhite mx-2">
          Advanced Settings
        </button>
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default PollCreate;
```

PollCreateAnswerOption.js:

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

const PollCreateAnswerOption = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [enteredAnswerOption, setEnteredAnswerOption] = useState();

  const answerOptionChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredAnswerOption(event.target.value);
    props.onAnswerOptionChange(event.target.value);
  };

  const deleteAnswerOptionHandler = (event) => {
    props.onAnswerOptionDelete(event);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <input
        type="text"
        className="mb-3 formtext w-full"
        placeholder="Add an answer..."
        onChange={answerOptionChangeHandler}
        ref={ref}
      ></input>
      <button
        className="btn-alt-onwhite p-1 h-9"
        type="button"
        onClick={deleteAnswerOptionHandler}
      >
        X
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});

export default PollCreateAnswerOption;
```

I'm OK with most of the form, but I'm confused on how I should generate 3 PollCreateAnswerOption components, allow the user to add and delete PollCreateAnswerOptions, and then put the data from each of them into my newPollData object.

I apologize in advance if the code is confusing or hard to read. There's a lot of things in here that are half-implemented from me trying all kinds of stuff. I tried to clean it up as much as I could.

There are currently both useState and useRef hooks in place because I don't know which I should use here and I was messing with both.

Thank you in advance to anyone who takes a look at this! I really appreciate the help, and I promise I did a lot of googling and reading before this point, but my brain is just fried at this point...

Comment: You can map over your array of answerOptions to render them. Here's [some documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components) on using map for rendering based on an array.

Comment: There's probably a better way to do this, but the first thing that springs to mind for handling passing callbacks to the `PollCreateAnswerOption` components is to modify `answerOptionChangeHandler` in `PollCreate.js` to accept an index and wrap it in another function before passing it to the `PollCreateAnswerOption` component.

Comment: For usability reasons, you might want to associate the labels in your answer poll form with their inputs.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I just realized you are using refs to retrieve the input values.

Comment: Hi @Calvin, thanks for the input! I currently have both state and ref half-implemented because I was just messing around trying to figure out the best way to do it. I'm happy to do it either way if I can just get it to work hahaha.

I do know how to create components by mapping over an array actually; however, I think the confusion there starts with not knowing what I should put in that array and then not understanding how to get my data back out of those generated components and into my data object (to eventually send to a database but that's a story for another day lol).

Comment: You can put the values of each `PollCreateOption` into the array. If you're using [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) the parent can handle the child's state and would have access to its data. Here is a simplified example: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-knuth-mvc5s?file=/src/components/dynamic-form.tsx (Note, this code is not optimized in any way and may perform poorly if there are lots of fields.)

Comment: Thanks a ton Calvin! Using your sample I was able to understand and get mine working!

I'm a little stuck on deleting an item now though. I have everything set up to remove the right item from the values array, but I must be doing something wrong when I update the state because when I click my delete button all of the other items disappear and the one I wanted to delete stays even though the array appears to have the correct values in it.

https://i.imgur.com/LCK5Laa.gif
https://i.imgur.com/rsK8EF4.png
https://i.imgur.com/5cKwjHY.png

Comment: The [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method returns an array of the deleted items. You also generally do not want to mutate state directly (`splice()` modifies the array it's called on). If you look at lines 10-14 of `dynamic-form.tsx` of the codesandbox I linked, I believe you can do something like that. Just remove the part where `value` gets inserted.

Comment: Ohhhhh I see. I was completely forgetting that splice would return the deleted value, and you're right just removing the value part from lines 10-14 works perfectly.

That said, even though it works I'm still having a little trouble wrapping my head around exactly what's happening here as I'm not super experienced with using the spread operator and whatnot. Would you mind explaining to me what exactly the code in the handleChange event in your sample is doing so I can make sure I fully understand this before I move on? Sorry for needing so much handholding!

Comment: In `handleChange()`, `setValues()` gets passed a function that takes the previous state and returns the next state based on it (this may not actually be needed). To generate a new array without mutating the original, `slice()` is used to to take specific sections of the original array. The first one creates an array of everything from elements 0 to `index ` - 1. The second gets elements from `index` + 1 to the end. The results are spread because we want their elements to be part of the new array. `value` is placed between these two sections.

Comment: Let `A` be the original array, `B` be `A.slice(0, index)` and `C` be `A.slice(index + 1)`. `B` is an array with elements from `A[0]` to `A[index - 1]`. `C` is an array of elements from `A[index + 1, end]`. Spreading is used because `B` and `C` are arrays, but we just want their elements to use in the final array. `B` gets spread which includes all elements before `index`, then `value`, then `C` is spread for all elements after `index`.

Comment: Some documentation on spreading that might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Thank you again! It makes so much more sense now. Thank you a ton for all of your help getting this figured out. I really appreciate your time and patience in helping me out. :)